# Pandas: Selectively Concatenating Columns based on Specific Value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Pandas and I'm struggling with a particular problem in concatenating columns in the proper manner, since it seems to combine aspects of all other problems I've researched.

My data contains multiple fields, the first 13 of which are all related to the serial number (columns named "sn1" thru "sn13"). The data beyond these fields is relevant, but not to this particular problem. The first 11 fields contains the actual serial number data, the remaining fields are a different problem to sort out later. These field names are stored in a list `serialname_list`

The format of the serial number is: XXX-XXXX-XXX

The only caveat is that some serial numbers are: XXX**A**-XXX-XXX

It's always "A" and it's always in in the "SN4" position (4th character). Each character is initially stored in its own field as an ASCII code. I'm trying to write a function to take in the dataframe, convert the ASCII codes to characters, format the serial number properly (based on whether or not "A" is present), store the formatted serial in field "Serial," then remove all the legacy fields.

I've gotten close with the following code, but it seems running the two functions sequentially over-writes the previous data with "NAN" for the serial numbers of the opposite format. I'm stumped on what I'm doing wrong to cause this, since I though I was properly selecting for rows which either `==A` or `!=A`.

Additionally, from my research on this, I feel like iterating through each element of the row is wrong, since it should be a vectorized solution. It seem's that my data is compatible with this (Rows either do or don't contain "A" and can be processed in any order) however, in practice I've be stumped by the proper application of Loc vs. Where vs. Apply vs. Query.

```
def convertserial(df):
    
    def long_serial(x):
        
        tempstring =''
         
        for i in range(len(serialname_list)-2):
            tempstring = tempstring + x['sn' + str(i+1)]
            if i == 3 or i == 7: #Follow pattern with adding dashes
                tempstring = tempstring + '-'
        return tempstring
    
    def normal_serial(x):
        
        tempstring =''

        for i in range(len(serialname_list)-2):
             tempstring = tempstring + x['sn' + str(i+1)]
             if i == 2 or i == 6: #Follow alternate pattern with adding dashes
                  tempstring = tempstring + '-'
        return tempstring
    
    df = df[serialname_list].apply(lambda x: x.map(chr)) #Convert ASCII codes to characters
    df['serial'] = df[df['sn4']=='A'].apply(long_serial,axis=1) #If A is present, longer than normal SN
    df['serial'] = df[df['sn4']!='A'].apply(normal_serial,axis=1) #If A is not present, normal
    return df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 def convertserial(df):
    df[serialname_list] = df[serialname_list].apply(lambda x: x.map(chr))
    mask = df['sn4'] == 'A'
    df['serial'] = df.apply(
        lambda x: f"{x['sn1']}{x['sn2']}{x['sn3']}-{'A-' if x['sn4'] == 'A' else ''}{x['sn5']}{x['sn6']}{x['sn7']}-{x['sn8']}{x['sn9']}{x['sn10']}",
        axis=1
    )
    df.drop(columns=serialname_list[:-1], inplace=True)
    return df
```

This seems to be working ran over a sample. This takes care of few things:

1. the case for which I think you are getting NaN, might be because the same column is being written twice. Once while checking for A and once for checking if it is not A. Here since there was no conditional check the second statements dominates the result.
2. We have hardcoded the sample template so no intervention of code based chenges
3. Fixing it also helps in cases where there data losses like in my runs I saw that the last 2 characters were getting skipped for the results where the answer is getting generated.

> ```
> Output:
>
>    sn1  sn2  sn3  sn4  sn5  sn6  sn7  sn8  sn9  sn10
> 0   74   79   76   66   87   74   72   65   86    80
> 1   81   66   89   65   86   67   89   81   80    65
> 2   82   81   78   66   90   82   79   80   71    80
> 3   65   68   80   66   82   78   88   90   80    77
> 4   86   73   70   66   74   68   83   65   84    86
> 5   79   83   78   66   84   77   65   71   73    76
> 6   89   84   76   66   83   78   87   74   85    69
> 7   73   68   71   66   76   68   82   68   65    70
> 8   77   67   87   66   68   79   70   65   73    65
> 9   76   82   81   65   86   66   65   71   70    79
>   sn10         serial
> 0    P    JOL-WJH-AVP
> 1    A  QBY-A-VCY-QPA
> 2    P    RQN-ZRO-PGP
> 3    M    ADP-RNX-ZPM
> 4    V    VIF-JDS-ATV
> 5    L    OSN-TMA-GIL
> 6    E    YTL-SNW-JUE
> 7    F    IDG-LDR-DAF
> 8    A    MCW-DOF-AIA
> 9    O  LRQ-A-VBA-GFO
> ```

For Data generation

```
data = {
    'sn1': np.random.randint(65, 91, size=10), 
    'sn2': np.random.randint(65, 91, size=10),
    'sn3': np.random.randint(65, 91, size=10),
    'sn4': [65 if np.random.rand() < 0.5 else np.random.randint(65, 91) for _ in range(10)],
    'sn5': np.random.randint(65, 91, size=10),
    'sn6': np.random.randint(65, 91, size=10),
    'sn7': np.random.randint(65, 91, size=10),
    'sn8': np.random.randint(65, 91, size=10),
    'sn9': np.random.randint(65, 91, size=10),
    'sn10': np.random.randint(65, 91, size=10),
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
serialname_list = ['sn1', 'sn2', 'sn3', 'sn4', 'sn5', 'sn6', 'sn7', 'sn8', 'sn9', 'sn10']
```

Comment: For fun people visiting what is the probability here of row having an "A" .  ;-)

Comment: This did it, thank you! I guess all my initial attempts vastly over-complicated it. My only confusion is you don't actually use the mask you set anywhere, should it be?

Comment: I was using it earlier but then also required a if block so just by-passed it. You can just ignore it.